# Check if value exists for a particular key in an array of dictionaries in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, dictionary

I have an `NSMutableArray` called `sourceData` which contains a number of dictionary objects all with the same keys: ID, NAME, CONTENT.

```
 [ //sourceData
   {ID:1, NAME:@"Bob", CONTENT:@"words"},
   {ID:2, NAME:@"Bob", CONTENT:@"words"},
   {ID:3, NAME:@"Bob", CONTENT:@"words")
 ];
```

I have another array of the same called `dataToAdd`. What I'd like to do is iterate through the array `dataToAdd` and only add the object into `sourceData` if the object DOESN'T have the same ID value.

In other words, how can I check in the array `sourceData` if it contains a dictionary object with an ID of X.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use predicates to filter the array.

```
NSArray *filtered = [sourceData filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(ID == %@)", @(ID_YOU_WANT_TO SEARCH)]];
```

This will return array of all the dictionaries which contain requested ID.

Answer (score 1):

Run a for-in loop on your `sourceData` for dictionaries, and get value for the key, which in this case is ID.

It should look something like this

```
for (NSDictionary *aDict in sourceData) {
   if ([[aDict objectForKey:@"ID"] intValue] == 1) {
       // id was indeed 1, replace '1', with the id that you're looking for
   }
}
```